# Broken Electorate badge?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

As I understand the electorate badge, I passed the requirements (600 total votes, at least 25% (150) on questions) a few days ago.  As I type this, my totals are: 602 votes, 221 on questions.  It has been a few days since I cast that 600th vote, but still no badge.  What's up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need **600 votes on questions**, with 25% or more of your votes on questions, not 600 total votes.

See the explanation [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/167443).

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my confusion.

Comment: oh, cool, I had the same question

Comment: This got me too when I first hit 600 ;D